# Datagrid ComboBoxColumn validation issues

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, validation, datagridcomboboxcolumn

(VS 2010)  I have a `DataGridComboBobxColum` in my WPF datagrid.  I'm trying to use a validation rule that is evaluated upon `UpdatedValue`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Model" x:Name="ModelCBColumn"  
                        ElementStyle="{StaticResource cbErrorStyle}"  >
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.SelectedItemBinding>
                    <Binding Path="Model" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:ModelValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.SelectedItemBinding>
```

The `ElementStyle` is then supposed to change the cell background and display a tooltip for validation errors:

```
<Style x:Key="cbErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

But my `ElementStyle` never gets applied.  Instead, for validation errors there is the default red border around the cell and a `!` icon in the row header.  No tooltip or yellow background.  Worse, when the cell is corrected, the red border will disappear but the `!` remains.  There are no row validation rules.   I have done a very similar approach for `TextBoxColumns` with no problems, so don't know what the issue is here.

Comment: 1. Use `Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent`
2. Any output into console?

Comment: Console is blank.  `CurrentItem` doesn't appear to change anything.  Considering that the `Background` setter is also not firing, I'm guessing the problem is deeper.  I'm wondering if `TargetType` should not be a combobox, but targeting TextBlock throws an error.

Comment: You could try `DataGridTemplateColumn` and set the style on the a combobox inside. I didn't mean for `CurrentItem` to be a fix, it's just a better way of getting the error item.

Comment: Ah thanks then.  Yeah I probably should give `TemplateColumn` a go.  Crossed fingers that doesn't open up another can of worms.

Comment: I know that its really too late but it works for me when i apply the style on property : EditingElementStyle